# In python, extracting non-English words

Tags: python, unicode

I have a text file that have English characters and other language characters.
And using code below, I want to extract some words from this file which is not English
particularly korean(Unicode range from AC00 to D7AF in UTF-8)

Is there any way to do this simple within this code??

Do I need to do something else?

```
....
text = f.read()
words = re.findall(r'\w+', dataString)
f.close()
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capital `\W` = Matches a *non*-alphanumeric character, *excluding* `_`.

```
>>> re.findall('[\W]+', u"# @, --►(Q1)-grijesh--b----►((Qf)), ");
[u'# @, --\u25ba(', u')-', u'--', u'----\u25ba((', u')), ']
```

From: [Unicode HOWTO?](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto) To read unicoded  text file use:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
for l in f:
  # regex code here
```

I have a file:

```
:~$ cat file
# @, --►(Q1)-grijesh--b----►((Qf)),
```

Reading it from Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open('file', encoding='utf-8')
>>> for l in f:
...  print re.findall('[\W]+', l)
... 
[u'# @, --\u25ba(', u')-', u'--', u'----\u25ba((', u')),\n']
>>>
```

To read alphabetic words try

```
>>> f = codecs.open('file', encoding='utf-8')
>>> for l in f:
...  print re.findall('[^\W]+', l)
... 
[u'Q1', u'grijesh', u'b', u'Qf']
```

Note: small `\w` Matches an alphanumeric character, *including* `_`.

Answer (score 0):

To find all characters in the range from AC00 to D7AF:

```
import re

L = re.findall(u'[\uac00-\ud7af]+', data.decode('utf-8'))
```

To find all non-ascii words:

```
import re

def isascii(word):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in word)

words = re.findall(u'\w+', data.decode('utf-8'))
non_ascii_words = [w for w in words if not isascii(w)]
```